# Makefile compiling advice

Tags: makefile

Can anyone figure out how to compile this?:https://github.com/robsoncouto/gm328a_rev_eng(I modified the Makefile but seem to be unable to compile it) it spits out this(i'm on mac but can switch to windows or ubuntu if it helps):

^~~~~~~~~~

2 errors generated.

natanon@Natanons-MacBook-Air firmware1.34 % gcc main.c ComponentTester.hex

In file included from main.c:24:

./config.h:667:4: error: <<< No or wrong MCU type selected! >>>

## error <<< No or wrong MCU type selected! >>>

^

In file included from main.c:25:

./common.h:24:10: fatal error: 'avr/io.h' file not found

## include

^~~~~~~~~~

Comment: This project is specific to AVR, it is supposed to be compiled with a cross-compiler for AVR microcontroller (i.e. avr-gcc). It seems that your attempt is to build it with native compiler, which probably won't work.